# How to implement moving buttons in an Android application

Tags: android, animation, drag

I have a variable number of buttons at the top of the screen, variable because each corresponds to a letter in a word and the word changes.
Then I have three buttons at the bottom which represent missing characters in the word that's at the top.

I'd like to give the user to give the chance to move one of the three possible characters and insert them in the word at the top. Say the buttons at the bottom are dash (-), apostrophe (') and space.

But after moving them, since more than one may be needed in the word, the moved button still be there.

So as an example "fillhimin" is the word at the top, which appears as a row of buttons, one button per letter.
At the bottom appear three buttons "-", "-", " " (space).

The user drags the space between the "l" and the "h", resulting in the word at the top being
"fill himin", the buttons at the bottom don't change.

Then the user drags the space again so that the word at the top is "fill him in". The buttons at the bottom don't change. The user can then move to the next word to fix by pressing a Next button.

The question is how would I implement this moving of the bottom buttons, with Drag and Drop, which seems quite complicated as I've seen it in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html or
with view property animation?

Comment: you can use textwatcher

Comment: Are you familiar with touch events?

Comment: I mean, that you don't need buttons at all. You just create List of drawables or bitmaps, where each element represents corresponding character. Then you create a custom view, with onDraw, which fully redraws it's state, depending on characters that forms the word at the top, characters at the bottom, position of finger in case if the user started to drag the button and so on. It will take time, but I suppose it will be much easier than designing and implementing logic of many buttons behavior.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Several points still unclear to me. Would I have to use 26 bitmaps of the letters of the alphabet? The onDraw can draw the button that is being moved and we get dragging animation for free. However there is no need to use the drag-and-drop events and machinery, just touch events, since I do not need most of what drag-and-drop offers, I'm just moving a drawable around. Is this right?